# How would you describe a person that has many achievements?

Tags: phrase-requests

I've thought of achiever, but I need an adjective.
For example: Todd has many achievements; he is ___________.

Comment: 'prolific' would require a noun to modify.   a 'prolific career' would suggest many career accomplishments but a "prolific person" could be taken to suggest he had a lot of children.  If you had a specific sentence or context where you'd use the adjective it might improve the odds of a good answer being there.

Comment: ***prolific*** seems to connote a high quantity of output and not necessarily related to achievements.

Comment: Psychologists call them ***high achievers*** : https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/youre-hired/201110/how-do-high-achievers-really-think

Answer (score 3):

"Accomplished" may be a good fit. It means either having achieved in many different things, or having mastered a particular body of knowledge.

A "Renaissance Man" is one who excells in many different things. Thomas Jefferson was a Renaissance Man: Statesman, botanist, vintner, writer.

Ella Fitzgerald was an accomplished musician. She performed masterfully for many years, solo and with other singers, in person and in the recording studio.

Answer (score 0):

***Prolific*** would work in many contexts ... the words and paragraph around it would tip people off I would hope.

with your example:
Todd has many achievements; he is ___prolific________.

> Definition of [prolific](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prolific)
>
> 1
>   :  producing young or fruit especially freely :  fruitful
>
> 2
>   archaic :  causing abundant growth, generation, or reproduction
>
> 3
>   :  **marked by abundant inventiveness or productivity**
>
> *a prolific composer*